# Action not being returned properly when triggered from Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

For some weird reason by action creator is not being called properly when I try to trigger it from my component. I am trying to return another function to dispatch to my reducers as is the standard with redux-thunk. However, I am unable to return anything.

The component is triggering the **'signinUser'** action function, the console.log displays the email and password values (line 7 of action file), and then it skips the return code (line 8 and onward) in action file.

Is there a silly mistake that I am making? All my other components work fine. I am using react version. 15.1

**ACTION**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {AUTH_USER, UNAUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR, ROOT_AUTH_URL} from '../constants/auth.constants';

export function signinUser({email, password}) {

  console.log('email and password in action', email, password); 

---- ^^^ THIS CONSOLE PART WORKS.
**---- THE RETURN FUNCTION below is not working... BELOW CODE IS NOT RENDERING ANYTHING.**-------

  return dispatch => {
console.log('pass the return'); ------> does not work :-(
    // Submit email/password to the server
axios.post(`${ROOT_AUTH_URL}signin`, {email, password})
.then(response => {
  console.log('response', response);
  // - Update state to indicate user is authenticated: flag will turn to "true"
      dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});
      // - Save the JWT token in local storage
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);

      // - redirect to the route '/feature'
      browserHistory.push('/');
    })
    .catch(() => {
                    // if request is bad...
                    // - Show an error to the user
      dispatch(authError('Bad Login Info!'));
    });
  }
}
**---- ABOVE RETURN STATEMENT DOES NOT WORK **-----------------
```

**COMPONENT**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {reduxForm, Field} from 'redux-form';
import {signinUser} from '../../actions/auth.actions';

class Signin extends Component {
    // used to take supplied inputs and check auth
  handleFormSubmit({email, password}) {
        // Need something to log user in
    console.log('test', email, password);

    signinUser({email, password});
    **^^^^^ THIS PART is TRIGERRING THE ACTION**
  }

  renderAlert() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
          <strong>Oops!</strong> {this.props.errorMessage}
        </div>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    // handleSubmit is a built in redux-form helper to bind ui to values
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <fieldset className="form-group">
          <label>Email:</label>
          <Field name="email" component="input" type="text" required className="form-control"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset className="form-group">
          <label>Password:</label>
          <Field name="password" component="input" type="password" required className="form-control"/>
        </fieldset>
        {this.renderAlert()}
        <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

Signin.propTypes = {
  signinUser: PropTypes.func,
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {errorMessage: state.auth.error};
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signin'
}, mapStateToProps, signinUser)(Signin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when I have a disconnect like this, and when I say generally I mean 200% of the time, it is because something is misspelled or missing. I notice that in your action:

```
UTH_USER, ROOT_AUTH_URL
```

are  in use, but

```
 UNAUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR
```

are not.

In the situation of unauth or an error I am not sure that this would do anything at all. Check the network tab of the browser devtools to look for an error, console.log everywhere else and check that spelling.

I hope you find it!

Comment: I figured it out. It had to do with redux-thunk not calling the dispatch function on line 10 when invoked. It called it before but I updated my component with updated redux-form version and I guess it somehow affected how redux thunk invokes returned functions. In the fix i simply resolve the promise in the action file and return an object with state and data.

Comment: so I basically return an object with data already retrieved instead of returning a method that thunk is then supposed invoke (but didn't) in this case for some reason.